# Switch function in C does all the cases

Tags: c, switch-statement

Okay so I'm writing a code for something and I've encountered a problem whilst testing switch function. It does all the cases incrementing from one's selection (my explanation). Could someone help me explain why is this so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ratedzfunctions.h"

int main()
{

    int selection, loop=1;
    FILE* fajl;

    //Opening the participants file
    fajl=fopen("participants.txt","r+");
    if (fajl==NULL)
    {
        printf("The file cannot be opened.\n");
    }

    //MENU
    do 
    {
        printf("\nMENU: \n------------\n1. RATEDZ\n\n2. STATISTICS\n\n3. EXIT\n\n==>");
        scanf("%d", &selection);

        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:
            ratedz(fajl);
        case 2:
            stats(fajl);
        case 3:
            loop=0;
        }
    }

    while (loop==1);

    fclose(fajl);

    return 0;
}

//THIS IS FROM RATEDZFUNCTIONS.H

void ratedz(FILE *fajl)
{
    printf("\nTEST RATEDZ");
}

void stats(FILE *fajl)
{
    //Printing all participants
    char *buffer=(char*) malloc(50);

    while(fscanf(fajl,"%s %s %s", buffer)!=EOF)
    {
        printf("\n%s %s %s", buffer);
    }

    free(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put a `break;` after each `case`.

The `switch/case` rule is easy, after a mached case, all following cases will be executed until a `break;` or end of `switch`:

```
switch (selection)
{
case 1:
       ...
       break;
case 2:
       ...
       break;
case 3:
       ...
       break; // Last break is not necessary
              // but it's good practice to put it.
}
```

---

There are good situations which removing `break;` is reasonable:

```
switch(letter) 
{
case 'i':
case 'a':
case 'o':
case 'u':
case 'e':
           printf ("Vowel!");
           break;
default :
           printf ("Consonant!");
           break;   
}
```

Comment: Oh, it's because I didn't rewind the file :P Silly me.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to add a `break;` statement after each `case`.

```
case 2:
    stats(fajl);
    break; /* <---- */
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not add a `break` at the end of each case it will just fall through to the next case:

```
switch (selection)
{
    case 1:
        ratedz(fajl);
        break ;
    case 2:
        stats(fajl);
        break ;
     /* ... */
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A `case` in a `switch` statement is treated like a label (see C.11 § 6.8.1). . There is actually no requirement to have any `case`s at all (See C.11 § 6.8.4).

```
switch (0) { /* do nothing */ }
```

The above code will compile just fine.

Since a `case` is like a label, there are no implicit semantics attached to it that would cause it to automatically jump outside the `switch`. Just as `break` is used to leave a loop block early, `break` is also used to leave a `switch` block early.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for `switch` staement in C

```
switch(expression)
{
     case (constant-expression) : staements  
     ....
     case (constant-expression) : staements
     default : statements
}
```

To work with a particular case your last statement in that group of statement must be `break`. 
Without the `break` statement , when the last statement in the `case` has been executed, control "falls through" to the first statement in the following `case`; the case label (const-expression) for the next `case` is ignored. Without `break` (or some jump statement), control will flow from one `case` into the next.

Comment: Actually the "syntax" for `switch` can be much more complicated than that. There can be any statement or block as depending statement, and `case` are just labels within that depending statement. What you describe is only one (very common) use case of `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

Some corrections,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ratedzfunctions.h"

int main()
{
    int selection, loop=1;
    FILE* fajl;

    //Opening the participants file
    fajl=fopen("participants.txt","r+");
    if (fajl==NULL)
    {
        printf("The file cannot be opened.\n");
        exit(1); //handle error when file cannot be opened...
    }

    //MENU
    do 
    {
        printf("\nMENU: \n------------\n1. RATEDZ\n\n2. STATISTICS\n\n3. EXIT\n\n==>");
        scanf("%d", &selection);

        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:
            ratedz(fajl);
break;
        case 2:
            stats(fajl);
break;
        case 3:
            loop=0;
break;
        default:
break;
        }
    }

    while (loop==1)
    {
    //do stuff here
    }
    fclose(fajl);

    return 0;
}
```